# cannot click on the navigation drawer using appium

Tags: appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STvaU.png)how do i click on th elements present in the navigation drawer,using 
driver.Xpath [this ia amazon app i want to just select the " books " from the navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRux.png)

Comment: you can use locator `by name` to perform action.

Comment: locator by name does n't work because the text  ("book") is not displayed in the ui automatorviewer,the text comes blank

Comment: What locator you get for that list of elements?

Comment: ("//android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[@id='drawer_layout']" +
"/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']" +
   "/android.widget.ViewAnimator[@index='0']" +
   "/android.widget.Framelayout[@id='web_view_frame]" +
   "/android.widget.Framelayout[@index='0']" +
   "/android.widget.Relativelayout[@index='0']" +
   "/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']" +
   "/android.webkit.WebView[@index='0']" +
   "/android.widget.ListView[@index='1']" +
   "/android.widget.ListView[@index='2']" +
   "/android.view.View[@index='9']"+
   "/android.view.View[@content-desc=''Electronics Link]");

Comment: the above was used to click on " Electronic link"

Comment: `("//android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[@id='drawer_layout']" + "/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.ViewAnimator[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.Framelayout[@id='web_view_frame]" + "/android.widget.Framelayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.Relativelayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']" + "/android.webkit.WebView[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.ListView[@index='1']" + "/android.widget.ListView[@index='2']" + "/android.view.View[@index=‘5’]”+ "/android.view.View[@content-desc=‘’Books”);` Try this xpath hope it works for you.

Comment: i tried this for selecting the book but this also didnt work

Comment: ("//android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[@id='drawer_layout']" + "/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.ViewAnimator[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.Framelayout[@id='web_view_frame]" + "/android.widget.Framelayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.Relativelayout[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='0']" + "/android.webkit.WebView[@index='0']" + "/android.widget.ListView[@index='1']" + "/android.widget.ListView[@index='2']" + "/android.view.View[@index=‘5’]”+ "/android.view.View[@content-desc="Books”]);

Answer (score 0):

Do this. It will click Left menu icon and opens navigation drawer

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Open navigation drawer").click();
```